# iPhone simulator just shows a white screen in XCode

Tags: xcode

Just downloaded the latest version of xcode. I'm a newbie and will appreciate any help I can get. I created a pretty basic app using the storyboard feature. It has 1 table view (with 3 rows; listed as red, blue, and green) and then when you click the red row it 'should' takes you to another screen where it tells you all about the color red in a text view window. However, when I go to launch the iphone simulator it just shows a white screen. I'm going to assume that I can't use the storyboard feature as a full blown creator and I'm going to need to add some code somewhere?

Comment: Show your code - how did you set delegate and datasource?

Comment: Hmm it's not letting me post the entire code from masterviewcontroller.m for some reason (I assume too much text). And basically I have three screens right now. Blank navigation controller > Table view controller > Detailed view controller.

Blank navigation controller has root view controller set at the table view controller. Table view controller has delegate and datasource set on itself. And detailed view controller has delegate view set on itself.